# Determine cluster membership in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

This is my vector before kmeans -

```
> sort(table(mydata))
mydata
23  7  9  4 10  3  5  8  2  1 
 1  3  3  4  5  6  6  6  7  9

km <- kmeans(mydata, centers = 10)
```

After kmeans -

```
> sort(table(km$cluster))
km$cluster
 1  6  7  3  5  2  4 10  8  9 
 1  3  3  4  5  6  6  6  7  9
```

Clearly, all my 1s are stored in cluster 9, all 2s are stored in Cluster 8 and so on.

Can I find using R which cluster a particular number belongs to? Say, finding which cluster my 1s are in?

Answer (score 5):

The values for `$cluster` are returned in the same order as your original data.

```
mydata <- rep(c(23,7,9,4,10,3,5,8,2,1), c(1,3,3,4,5,6,6,6,7,9))
sort(table(mydata))
# mydata
# 23  7  9  4 10  3  5  8  2  1 
#  1  3  3  4  5  6  6  6  7  9 

km <- kmeans(mydata, centers = 10) 
unique(cbind(value=mydata, clust=km$cluster))
#       value clust
#  [1,]    23     9
#  [2,]     7     5
#  [3,]     9     7
#  [4,]     4     4
#  [5,]    10     1
#  [6,]     3    10
#  [7,]     5     2
#  [8,]     8     8
#  [9,]     2     6
# [10,]     1     3
```

Here i've just re-joined the two with cbind and used `unique` to eliminate all the dups since you have such discrete data.

Answer (score 2):

Extending on MrFlick's answer (upvoted), and in case you want the cluster number programmatically, you could do also this (utilizing the `magrittr` package, to get rid of all these nested parentheses):

```
library(magrittr)
data.point <- 5  # put the data point here
cluster.no <- c(mydata==data.point)  %>% which %>% km$cluster[.] %>% unique
```

Examples:

```
library(magrittr)
set.seed(42)  # for reproducibility
mydata <- rep(c(23,7,9,4,10,3,5,8,2,1), c(1,3,3,4,5,6,6,6,7,9))
km <- kmeans(mydata, centers = 10) 

data.point <- 23
c(mydata==data.point)  %>% which %>% km$cluster[.] %>% unique
# 8
data.point <- 10
c(mydata==data.point)  %>% which %>% km$cluster[.] %>% unique
# 1
```